# How to start and end a dynamically generetad datetime highchart's xAxis on the first and last tick

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have several different highcharts that all can vary on what date-time they start and stop, so a hard-coded solution will not work.

**What I am trying to achieve** is to have the xAxis labels start at the first data point's datetime, and end at the last point's datetime.

What highchart allows me to do is some thing like this

```
xAxis: {
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        showFirstLabel: true,
        showLastLabel: true
}
```

This simply means the xAxis itself starts and ends on *a* tick, not necessarily the first and last tick of data. It also show a large padding/space at the left and right side of the chart to make sure the xAxis can start and and end on a tick, but as I said, these rules don't regard the series content, and simply start and end on whatever tick interval the chart calculates on its own.

**Ideally**, a chart that has data from "1 jan. 2017" to "20 feb. 2017"  should have labels that that with 1 jan. and end with 20 feb.

**Instead**, the chart will maybe start with 5 jan. and end on 15 feb. which I think it does to accommodate vertical space for the labels.

I suspect maybe it could be possible to take the data length, and calculate a perfect amount of steps so it shows the first and last date?

Comment: Can you make a live example of the problem? Your starting point can be this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qq3d6omv/ You can also try using tickPositioner/tickPositions http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions

Comment: @morganfree That fiddle actually already demonstrates my problem! If you shrink the Results window so the chart is horizontally squeezed, you will see that the only ticks available are 1. feb and 8. feb. Instead of 1.feb and 12. feb which is the last date in the chart. The same thing is happening in my charts. My charts are not as small as you would have to make this chart to see the problem, but they hold a lot of data, which i suspect causes the problem anyway. Ideally i would see the first and last, together with enough ticks between to make the chart readable

Comment: use a tick positioner to dynamically set ticks in the axis - the logic how you position the ticks is up to you - http://jsfiddle.net/qq3d6omv/1/ you can add some collision detection to prevent labels to overlap - two last tick labels may collide with each other http://jsfiddle.net/qq3d6omv/2/

Comment: This looks like it will put me in the right direction, thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of morganfree, I figured out how to calculate a set of tick positions that give you the first and last tick of data in the chart.

In my solution i used moment.js to get the milisecond value as I had it handy.

```
        tickPositioner: function () {
            const tiPo = [];
            const range = this.dataMax - this.dataMin;
            const steps = Math.floor(this.width / 40) //40 is the the pixel distance you want bewtween ticks
            const mpi = range / steps //milisec per interval
            for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
                tiPo.push(moment(this.dataMin + (mpi * i)).startOf("day").valueOf())
            }
            tiPo.push(this.dataMax)
            tiPo.info = this.tickPositions.info
            return tiPo
        },
        endOnTick: false,
```

I also found that setting `enOnTick` to `false` helped in letting the chart automatically set the distance on the right side, so the last label doesn't overflow or get too close to the edge of the chart (if you have a border or something around the chart)